# calculate the percentage in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi I want to calculate the percentage of this columns:

[image: percentage]

I used this formula for calculating the percentage of order_units of all units if auction_id is the same:

```
=IF((A2=A3),C2/D2)
```

it's for auction_id = 20 but for auction_id=19 i changed the formula :

```
=IF((A17=A18),C17/D$17)
```

and so on...

I have more than 200 rows if there any easy way to do that with formula or vba code ?

Comment: What are the formulas in `D2` and `D17`, or are they hard-coded values?

Comment: So how many different formulas are we talking about and is there any logic to when you need them to change?

Comment: D is fixed data is the sum of order _units , some of bidders_id have canceled there orders so it cann't be summed with them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIF to get the total:

```
=C2/SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly a nested if statement would suit your needs.

An example is:

```
=IF(A1<>B1,IF(A1>B1,A1*B1,A1/B1))
```

If you want to see how this works just put 3 in cell A1 and 4 in cell B1 and then this formula in cell C1 and you should get `.75`

Also, you can use google and YouTube for further help. If this was not what you are asking then I hope you get a helpful comment!

Comment: BigBen, your sumifs answers the question nicely. Nice job catching that.

Comment: Well it only worked when OP updated the question with a new screenshot, but thanks :)